# whats the difference between calendar lists on SP 2010 and 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, modal-dialog, sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events

In SP 2010 clicking on a event in Calendar list opens the event in a modal dialog box, but the same in SP 2013 opens in a new page. Is it configurable? Any other differences?

Answer (score 2):

In SP 2013, new event can open in modal popup. To change that setting you need to `navigate to Calendar List settings --> Advanced List setting --> Dialogs : Launch forms in dialog ? Yes/No.`